# Mysql Triggers with two tables

Tags: triggers, mysql-8.0

I have edited my previous question as I noticed wasn't correctly formulated.

Currently, I have two Tables:

`ocok_country`

```
| status | country_id |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1    | 1            |
| 1   | 2            |
| 0    | 3            |
| 0   | 4            |
```

** country_id 3 and 4 not updated with the trigger **

`ocok_zone_to_geo_zone`

```
| name | country_id |
| -------- | -------------- |
| ABC    | 1            |
| DEF   | 2            |
| new-country-zone    | 3            |
| new-country-zone   | 4            |
```

I have created a query that will Update the table `ocok_county.status` to `1` IF the `ocok_zone_to_geo_zone.country_id` Exist - see Country_id 1 and 2 on the tables

```
UPDATE ocok_country c
SET c.status = CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ocok_zone_to_geo_zone s
            WHERE s.country_id = c.country_id
        ) THEN '1'
        ELSE '0'
    END;
```

Now, I have also tried to create a trigger that will do this and save me some time but, I cannot find where is the error and I'll appreciate your help on this one
Thanks!
See country_id 3 and 4 not updated in status

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_ocok_zone_trigger AFTER UPDATE
ON
    `ocok_country` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS
        (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `ocok_zone_to_geo_zone`
        WHERE
            `country_id` = NEW.country_id
    ) THEN
UPDATE
    `ocok_country`
SET
    `status` = '1'
WHERE
    `country_id` = NEW.country_id;
END IF;
END;
```

Currently using `mysql 8.0.32`

Comment: ??you can’t set something which does not exist? Please post a worked example

Comment: So show the trigger code that you've started, and where you may be stuck. We're not here to write those for you, but know in advance that you cannot reference the same table within the trigger's action.

Comment: Questions were already answer in [enter link description here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/323398/mysql-trigger-update-status-id-if-the-value-exist-in-other-table/323401#323401)